# Google Cloud Storage requires storage.objects.create permission when reading from pyspark

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-platform, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I'm trying to read pyspark DataFrame from Google Cloud Storage, but I keep getting an error that the service account has no storage.objects.create permissions. The account does not have WRITER permissions, but it's just reading parquet files:

```py
spark_session.read.parquet(input_path)

18/12/25 13:12:00 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl: Repairing batch of 1 missing directories.
18/12/25 13:12:01 ERROR com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl: Failed to repair some missing directories.
com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "***.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to ***.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "***.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to ***."
}
```

Comment: Where are you running this code from? Also, does the error go away when adding 'storage.objects.create' permission to the Service Account?

Comment: @Maxim , I'm running this code on a pyspark app running on a dataproc cluster and scheduled with Airflow. I cannot test that because this account cannot get this access level

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We found the issue. It's due to the implicit auto repair feature in the GCS connector. We disabled this behavior by setting `fs.gs.implicit.dir.repair.enable` to `false`.

Comment: for those who may not know, the above happens in hadoop configuration within spark context, if using pyspark: sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.implicit.dir.repair.enable","false")

Answer (score 2):

Please see this question: [Why does Spark running in Google Dataproc store temporary files on external storage (GCS) instead of local disk or HDFS while using saveAsTextFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170932/why-does-spark-running-in-google-dataproc-store-temporary-files-on-external-stor)

Spark will create temporary files when doing some actions. I have run into this when extracting data from GCS files and converting to a user-defined object. It can also do this when loading into BQ because writing to Storage and then executing a single load from GCS is more efficient. You can see the change which did that [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes#november_8_2016).

Sadly, there is no concrete link I can give you because the problem is not documented, as far as I know. I will try to find one for you and will update my response if I succeed.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan. So, are you suggesting that DataFrame.read() might be one of these actions? Are you familiar with any parameter that I can set to avoid that?