# Writing Spark dataframe as parquet to S3 without creating a _temporary folder

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Using pyspark I'm reading a dataframe from parquet files on Amazon S3 like

```
dataS3 = sql.read.parquet("s3a://" + s3_bucket_in)
```

This works without problems. But then I try to write the data

```
dataS3.write.parquet("s3a://" + s3_bucket_out)
```

I do get the following exception

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o39.parquet.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: 
Relative path in absolute URI: s3a://<s3_bucket_out>_temporary
```

It seems to me that Spark is trying to create a `_temporary` folder first, before it is writing to write into the given bucket. Can this be prevent somehow, so that spark is writing directly to the given output bucket?

Comment: I have posted a solution for this problem here ( if you are working with EMR ) https://stackoverflow.com/a/54350777/1931239

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/big-data/improve-apache-spark-write-performance-on-apache-parquet-formats-with-the-emrfs-s3-optimized-committer/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't eliminate the _temporary file as that's used to keep the intermediate 
work of a query hidden until it's complete

But that's OK, as this isn't the problem. The problem is that the output committer gets a bit confused trying to write to the root directory (can't delete it, see)

You need to write to a subdirectory under a bucket, with a full prefix. e.g.
`s3a://mybucket/work/out` .

I should add that trying to commit data to S3A is not reliable, precisely because of the way it mimics `rename()` by what is something like `ls -rlf src | xargs -p8 -I% "cp % dst/% && rm %"`. Because `ls` has delayed consistency on S3, it can miss newly created files, so not copy them.

See: [Improving Apache Spark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgHrff5yAQo) for the details.

Right now, you can only reliably commit to s3a by writing to HDFS and then copying. EMR s3 works around this by using DynamoDB to offer a consistent listing

Comment: Could I then force spark to not put the `_temporary` folder onto S3, but store it locally instead?

Comment: no, because it's a core part of the commit algorithm. Executors write data under _temporary; when all the workers are finished then the driver commits it with rename...which only works within a single filesystem.

Comment: @SteveLoughran Hello Steeve, I've just see this conference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgHrff5yAQo where they thank you by the way, is there an better way 1 year after or is it still the same issue ?

Comment: Yes, the S3A Committers in Hadoop 3.1 (shipping in HDP-3.0) don't use rename to commit work. We lifted a lot of code from Ryan Blye. Ryan is busy on Iceberg these days too: take a look at that

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when writing the root of S3 bucket:

```
df.save("s3://bucketname")
```

I resolved it by adding a `/` after the bucket name:

```
df.save("s3://bucketname/")
```