# Add `hadoop-cloud` to Spark's classpath

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

Since the recent announcement of S3 strong consistency on reads and writes, I would like to try new S3A committers such as the magic one.

According to the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cloud-integration.html#committing-work-into-cloud-storage-safely-and-fast), we need to add the two class paths: `BindingParquetOutputCommitter` and `PathOutputCommitProtocol` adde in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/2ac6163a5d04027ef4dbdf7d031cddf9415ed25e).

The official documentation suggests using Spark built with hadoop3.2 profile. Is there any way to add the two classes without recompiling Spark? (I cannot use already built Spark for some technical reasons)

I am using Spark 3.0.1

I already checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993446/s3guard-and-parquet-magic-commiter-for-s3a-on-emr-6-x) but unfortunately, the OP switched to open source S3A committers to provided one by EMR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a version of spark built with the -Phadoop-cloud module. which adds the  new classes into spark-hadoop-cloud.jar, and adds in the relevant dependencies, which for S3A are

```
hadoop-aws-${the-exact-version-of-hadoop-jars-you-have}.jar
aws-sdk-something-${the-exact-version-that-hadoop-jar-was-built-with}.jar
```

so you could check out the spark branch you use, and do a maven build only of that module

```
mvn -pl hadoop-cloud -Phadoop-cloud -Dhadoop.version=$hadoop-version install -DskipTests
```

and you get a new spark-hadoop-cloud JAR which you can use with the new stuff

- the s3a committers only came in with hadoop-3.1
- we (I) have been busy fielding some race conditions with jobIDs and the "staging committer"
- and, given S3 is consistent, I'd recommend the magic committer.

You can test this stuff in spark standalone, just do some minimal job to write data and verify that the _SUCCESS file contains some JSON summary of the job.

Whichever committer you use, make sure your buckets are set up to delete incomplete uploads after a few days. You should do that everywhere anyway.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer and your work on committers. I finally figured out with all the docs you've written, I won't delete this question as I think this is one of the clearest answers currently.

Comment: see: https://github.com/steveloughran/zero-rename-committer/releases  .

Answer (score 1):

If you are building with stevel’s mvn command you should include the `-Phadoop-3.2` flag as well so that the `extra-source-dir` flag is picked up in pom.xml and compiles the committer classes into the JAR. So the full command would be `mvn -pl hadoop-cloud -Phadoop-cloud -Phadoop-3.2 -Dhadoop.version=$hadoop-version install -DskipTests`. See https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/de351e30a90dd988b133b3d00fa6218bfcaba8b8/hadoop-cloud/pom.xml#L207