# spark: long delay between jobs, why spark would save tables on driver?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was running spark sql on Yarn and I met the same issue like below link:
[Spark: long delay between jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524945/spark-long-delay-between-jobs)

There's a long delay post the action which was saving table.
On Spark UI, I could see the particular **saveAsTable()** job was completed but there's no any new job was submitted.
[spark ui screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZmYe.png)

In the first link, the answer said I/O operations will occur on master node but I doubt that.

At the gap time, I checked hdfs where I saved the tables, then I could see *_temporary* file rather than *_success* file. it looks like the answer is truth and spark was saving table on driver end. Why?!!

I'm using below code to save table:

```js
dataframe.write.partitionBy(partitionColumn)).format(format)
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.saveAsTable(s"$tableName")
```

BTW, the format is orc format file. 
anyone can give me some suggestions? :) 
thx in advance.

Comment: not sure if my change that increased spark.sql.shuffle.partitions to 2000 where's 200 by default resulted in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Spark SQL - Difference between df.repartition and DataFrameWriter partitionBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416357/spark-sql-difference-between-df-repartition-and-dataframewriter-partitionby)
As per above link, **partitionBy is used to partition data on disk.** so this process cannot be monitored on Spark UI.
I increased the partitions numbers before calling partitionBy(), then too much files would be generated, which caused the delay.
I think that's the truth.